# Unpin app from taskbar, startmenu using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am developing an installer using Inno Setup targeting XP, Win7, 8. I need the app icon to be pinned to taskbar and the startmenu. So far I have been able to do that.

Now, when the user uninstalls this program, the pinned items should be unpinned. I haven't managed to find a solution to this.

Please guide.

Comment: You've said that you were able to pin an icon to the taskbar and start menu. How ? I'm asking to suggest a corresponding reverse action. Besides, as far as I know, you cannot pin icons programatically, so what you claim is quite surprising to me...

Comment: I used this as a reference. http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/12263-inno-setup-a-way-to-pin-a-shortcut-onto-taskbar-in-code/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said that you have used a function from [`this link`](http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/12263-inno-setup-a-way-to-pin-a-shortcut-onto-taskbar-in-code/). I assume the one from [`this post`](http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/12263-inno-setup-a-way-to-pin-a-shortcut-onto-taskbar-in-code/#entry107891):

```
procedure zylPinAppToTaskbar(strPath, strApp: string);  
var  
  vShell, vFolder, vFolderItem, vItemVerbs: Variant;  
  vPath, vApp: Variant;
  i: Integer;
  sItem: String;
  h: LongInt;
  szPinName: String;
  filenameEnd : Integer;
  filename    : String;
  strEnd    : String;
begin 
  SetLength(szPinName, 255);
  h := LoadLibrary(ExpandConstant('{sys}\Shell32.dll'));
  LoadString(h, 5386, szPinName, 255);
  FreeLibrary(h);
  strEnd := #0;
  filenameEnd := Pos(strEnd, szPinName);
  filename := Copy(szPinName, 1, filenameEnd - 1);
  if (Length(filename) > 0) then  //WinXp or lower, no pin taskbar function
  begin
    vShell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
    vPath := strPath;
    vFolder := vShell.NameSpace(vPath);
    vApp := strApp;
    vFolderItem := vFolder.ParseName(vApp);
    vItemVerbs := vFolderItem.Verbs;

  for i := 1 to vItemVerbs.Count do
  begin
    sItem := vItemVerbs.Item(i).Name;

    if (sItem = filename) then
    begin
      // 63 63 72 75 6E 2E 63 6F 6D
      vItemVerbs.Item(i).DoIt;
      break;
     end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That's really hacky way (which I wouldn't rely on). Let's focus now on what it actually does. The function loads the `Shell32.dll` library and reads from its string table the caption of the popup menu item that belongs to the *Pin this program to taskbar* feature (and stores it into the `filename` variable). Then it connects to Shell and creates the [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787868(v=vs.85).aspx) object for the passed folder path (`vFolder` variable). For this folder object it then creates the [`FolderItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787810(v=vs.85).aspx) object (`vFolderItem` variable) and on this object iterates all the available verbs (`vItemVerbs` variable) and checks if the `Name` matches the one read from the `Shell32.dll` library. If it finds one, it invokes the action by the [`DoIt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774170(v=vs.85).aspx) method and breaks the iteration.

Now if you know what the above code does, you can guess that the only thing you need to do to perform the unpin action is finding the caption of the popup menu item for that feature. I've looked into the string table of the `Shell32.dll` library and the *Unpin this program from taskbar* string has ID 5387, so the only thing to modify the above function for unpinning is changing this line:

```
// this magical 5386 value is the ID of the "Pin this program to taskbar"
// popup menu caption string in the Shell32.dll string table
LoadString(h, 5386, szPinName, 255);
```

To this:

```
// this magical 5387 value is the ID of the "Unpin this program from taskbar"
// popup menu caption string in the Shell32.dll string table
LoadString(h, 5387, szPinName, 255);
```

But I do not recommend that way. There is no official way to pin program to taskbar because that's been reserved for the user to decide.

---

As a bonus, I wrote the following wrapper for the above code:

```
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

const
  // these constants are not defined in Windows
  SHELL32_STRING_ID_PIN_TO_TASKBAR = 5386;
  SHELL32_STRING_ID_PIN_TO_STARTMENU = 5381;
  SHELL32_STRING_ID_UNPIN_FROM_TASKBAR = 5387;
  SHELL32_STRING_ID_UNPIN_FROM_STARTMENU = 5382;

type
  HINSTANCE = THandle;
  HMODULE = HINSTANCE;

  TPinDest = (
    pdTaskbar,
    pdStartMenu
  );

function LoadLibrary(lpFileName: string): HMODULE;
  external 'LoadLibrary{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function FreeLibrary(hModule: HMODULE): BOOL;
  external 'FreeLibrary@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function LoadString(hInstance: HINSTANCE; uID: UINT;
  lpBuffer: string; nBufferMax: Integer): Integer;
  external 'LoadString{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

function TryGetVerbName(ID: UINT; out VerbName: string): Boolean;
var
  Buffer: string;
  BufLen: Integer;
  Handle: HMODULE;
begin
  Result := False;

  Handle := LoadLibrary(ExpandConstant('{sys}\Shell32.dll'));
  if Handle <> 0 then
  try
    SetLength(Buffer, 255);
    BufLen := LoadString(Handle, ID, Buffer, Length(Buffer));

    if BufLen <> 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      VerbName := Copy(Buffer, 1, BufLen);
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Handle);
  end;
end;

function ExecVerb(const FileName, VerbName: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Shell: Variant;
  Folder: Variant;
  FolderItem: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;

  Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  Folder := Shell.NameSpace(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
  FolderItem := Folder.ParseName(ExtractFileName(FileName));

  for I := 1 to FolderItem.Verbs.Count do
  begin
    if FolderItem.Verbs.Item(I).Name = VerbName then
    begin
      FolderItem.Verbs.Item(I).DoIt;
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;  
end;

function PinAppTo(const FileName: string; PinDest: TPinDest): Boolean;
var
  ResStrID: UINT;
  VerbName: string;
begin
  case PinDest of
    pdTaskbar: ResStrID := SHELL32_STRING_ID_PIN_TO_TASKBAR;
    pdStartMenu: ResStrID := SHELL32_STRING_ID_PIN_TO_STARTMENU;
  end;
  Result := TryGetVerbName(ResStrID, VerbName) and ExecVerb(FileName, VerbName);
end;

function UnpinAppFrom(const FileName: string; PinDest: TPinDest): Boolean;
var
  ResStrID: UINT;
  VerbName: string;
begin
  case PinDest of
    pdTaskbar: ResStrID := SHELL32_STRING_ID_UNPIN_FROM_TASKBAR;
    pdStartMenu: ResStrID := SHELL32_STRING_ID_UNPIN_FROM_STARTMENU;
  end;
  Result := TryGetVerbName(ResStrID, VerbName) and ExecVerb(FileName, VerbName);
end;
```

And its possible usage, for pinning:

```
if PinAppTo(ExpandConstant('{sys}\calc.exe'), pdTaskbar) then
  MsgBox('Calc has been pinned to the taskbar.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
if PinAppTo(ExpandConstant('{sys}\calc.exe'), pdStartMenu) then
  MsgBox('Calc has been pinned to the start menu.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

And for unpinning:

```
if UnpinAppFrom(ExpandConstant('{sys}\calc.exe'), pdTaskbar) then
  MsgBox('Calc is not pinned to the taskbar anymore.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
if UnpinAppFrom(ExpandConstant('{sys}\calc.exe'), pdStartMenu) then
  MsgBox('Calc is not pinned to the start menu anymore.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it. Here's the code to pin and unpin from the startmenu and taskbar.

```
oShell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
objFolder := oShell.Namespace(ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\My_Path'));
objFolderItem := objFolder.ParseName('MyApp.exe');
colVerbs := objFolderItem.Verbs();
for i := 0 to colverbs.count() do
begin
   VerbName := lowercase(colverbs.item(i).name);
   StringChangeEx(VerbName,'&','',true);
   if (CompareText(Verbname, 'Pin to Start Menu') = 0) then
     colverbs.item(i).DoIt
   if (CompareText(Verbname, 'Pin to Taskbar') = 0) then
     colverbs.item(i).DoIt
end;
```

Change the compare string to 'Unpin from Start Menu' and 'Unpin from Taskbar' at the time of unpinning.

Comment: That won't work on non english Windows. For instance in my system are those menu pinning items called *"Připnout na hlavní panel"* and *"Připnout k nabídce Start"*. As you can see, none of them would match your pattern. Reading those captions from Shell32.dll string table has its place in that code.

Comment: You are right.. I was happy to have it running that I couldn't wait to post it! :P

Comment: So I actually spoiled your mood. As a compensation for that I wrote a bit more generic code for you :-)

Comment: Thanks a tonnne for the generic code as well!! And no, my mood wasn't spoiled.. I saw your answer and I saw my (novice) answer... and I was amused with myself..!! :)

Comment: @TLama Under certain versions of Window 8.1, the string seem to be no longer located in Shell32.exe. I am not sure where exactely they are now.

Comment: @tmighty, pity. But I'm afraid I'm out of help here (have no Windows 8.1 by hand). It was, and still is a hack. You can hardcode the menu item captions as shown in this answer, but you'll need to count with the consequences I mentioned.

Comment: @poortip How are you unpinning from Windows 10 nowadays? Any code that works which you use for Windows 10 20H2 version that does the trick?