# How to unpin icons of 2 programs(diff versions) of the same name during uninstall using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I have an installer that installs 2 sets of apps by the same name, but having different versions. These apps have to be pinned to the taskbar and the start menu too.

The installation has no problem. The problem is when I try to uninstall. If only one of the versions is installed, then the un-installation goes smoothly and the icons are removed from the taskbar and start menu. But, if both are installed, then the first version is uninstalled, and the second gives an exception. I guess it has something to do with both the apps having the same name.

Here is the code for unpinning the icons which TLama helped me with here [Unpin app from taskbar, startmenu using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983025/unpin-app-from-taskbar-startmenu-using-inno-setup/25060377?noredirect=1#comment38989789_25060377)

I know I haven't yet included the perfect code by TLama. I am still using the raw version,

```
oShell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
objFolder := oShell.Namespace(ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\My_Path'));
objFolderItem := objFolder.ParseName('MyApp.exe');
colVerbs := objFolderItem.Verbs();
for i := 0 to colverbs.count() do
begin
   VerbName := lowercase(colverbs.item(i).name);
   StringChangeEx(VerbName,'&','',true);
   if (CompareText(Verbname, 'Pin to Start Menu') = 0) then
     colverbs.item(i).DoIt
   if (CompareText(Verbname, 'Pin to Taskbar') = 0) then
     colverbs.item(i).DoIt
end;
```

I get a Nil pointer exception at

```
colVerbs := objFolderItem.Verbs();
```

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you got a *"Variant is null, cannot invoke."* exception at the line which invokes the `Verbs` method of the `objFolderItem` object, it means the `objFolderItem` object is `NULL` which points to the fact that `ParseName` method call failed. In other words, the file was not found in that folder.

Note, that you can use those functions only for existing files and folders, so make sure you are calling it before they are uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, I understand that... And the problem was a silly mistake at my end. Thanks!